# How to define functions for class in different file in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, class, methods

I have a swift class that has about 10 different functions in it. It's over 400 lines of code and needs to be broken up. I want to put some functions in different files. What is the best way to do this? Maybe inheritance?

Comment: What exactly is the nature of the class and these 10 functions? Knowing that would help us know how i might be appropriate to split them up. And why are 10 functions averaging 40 lines each? (that's waaaaaay to long for a function.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create different files and then put some method in there within `extension`.

Example:

```
class MyMessyViewController: UIViewController {
    var oneVariable: String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       anotherFunctionFromThisExtension()
    }

    func one(){
    }
    func two(){
    }
    func three(){
    }
}
```

Then Create a new file and put more functions into this file within an extension.

```
extension MyMessyViewController {

    func anotherFunctionFromThisExtension() {
       oneVariable = "I made this change from this File"
       print(oneVariable)
    }
}
```

Best practice if you have Delegates, Collection/TableViews in you view controller, you can separate them with extensions, just instead of simple `extension MyMessyViewController { }` write like `extension MyMessyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource { }`

Comment: I think it's actually best to split `UICollectionViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDataSource` etc. into separate classes entirely. Extensions make your VC look smaller, but it's still one giant monolithic class that does too many things, shares too much state between the different sets of unrelated functions.